# Syntax Error when Using Case Statement (with Between before the statement)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using CASE statement in the where of a Select Statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM [4c1917a7-2bab-4dbe-bb22-812a25a8930f] AS TP 
INNER JOIN TSaisie AS TS ON TP.[TInd_FK_ID] = TS.[TSai_FK_TInd_ID]
WHERE 
    TS.[TSai_Date] BETWEEN 
            CASE WHEN (SELECT SeasonDate2 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest)) < (SELECT SeasonDate1 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest))
            THEN
                (SELECT SeasonDate2 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest)) AND (SELECT SeasonDate1 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest))
            ELSE
                (SELECT SeasonDate1 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest)) AND (SELECT SeasonDate2 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest))
            END
        AND [TSai_FK_TPro_ID] = 354
GROUP BY TInd_BagueID, TP.[DateSaisie]
```

This is throwing a syntax error near the keyword "AND" and "ELSE"

Please can someone suggest what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've missed here is the position of AND keyword. It should be something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM [4c1917a7-2bab-4dbe-bb22-812a25a8930f] AS TP 
INNER JOIN TSaisie AS TS ON TP.[TInd_FK_ID] = TS.[TSai_FK_TInd_ID]
WHERE 
    TS.[TSai_Date] BETWEEN 
            CASE WHEN (SELECT SeasonDate2 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest)) < (SELECT SeasonDate1 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest))
            THEN
                (SELECT SeasonDate2 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest)) 
            ELSE
                (SELECT SeasonDate1 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest))
            END

            AND 

            CASE WHEN (SELECT SeasonDate2 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest)) < (SELECT SeasonDate1 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest))
            THEN
                (SELECT SeasonDate1 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest)) 
            ELSE
                (SELECT SeasonDate2 FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest)) 
            END

        AND [TSai_FK_TPro_ID] = 354
GROUP BY TInd_BagueID, TP.[DateSaisie]
```

But I would really advise to use some local variables to fetch the dates first and use it in query. Like,

```
DECLARE @SeasonDate1 date, @SeasonDate2 date
SELECT @SeasonDate1 = SeasonDate1,
       @SeasonDate2 = SeasonDate1
FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest)
SELECT *
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE ModifiedDate 
    BETWEEN CASE
           WHEN @SeasonDate1 < @SeasonDate2 THEN @SeasonDate1
           ELSE @SeasonDate2
       END AND CASE
           WHEN @SeasonDate1 < @SeasonDate2 THEN @SeasonDate2
           ELSE @SeasonDate1
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

It currently doesn't make sense. In both your `THEN` and `ELSE` clauses, you have two expressions with an AND between them.

I suspect the `SELECT` clauses after the ANDs along with the ANDs themselves, shouldn't be there. The expression after `THEN` and `ELSE` should only evaluate to a single value.

I think your `CASE` statement should just be:

```
 CASE
     WHEN
            (SELECT SeasonDate2
             FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest)) <
            (SELECT SeasonDate1
             FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest)) THEN
            (SELECT SeasonDate2
             FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest))
     ELSE
            (SELECT SeasonDate1
             FROM fn_GetSeasonDates(@Datetest))
 END
```

Comment: Ok, I have to use 2 case when and it works with the between

Comment: `CASE` **expression**; there are no `Case` statements in SQL Server.